# Array not being sent from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, macos

I am working on a personal project that will allow me to log all the Scottish Mountains (munros) I have walked. I often walk two, or 3 a day so I needed a dynamic form to control how many fields to have.

I planned to store the data about the mountains in 4 arrays, Name, Height, Location and Closest Town.

When I enter the data into the form, I then hit submit and try to display the names on the screen to check that the form is working correctly.

I can't seem to get the arrays working although I do have other elements being displayed successfully (the date of the hike for example).

Below is the html

```
<form name="munroForm" action="process.php" class="register" method="POST">
        <h1>Munro Data Entry Form</h1>
        <fieldset class="row1">
            <legend>Trip Date</legend>
            <p>
                <label>Date of Trip*</label>
                <input type="date" required name="date">
            </P>
        </fieldset> 

        <fieldset class="row1">
        <legend>Munro Details</legend>

           <table id="munroTable" class="form" border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength = "30" required="required" name="name[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label>Height *</label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength = "5" required="required" name="height[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label>Location</label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength = "20" name="location[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label>Closest Town</label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength = "15" name="closest_town[]">

                     </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <p> 
                <input type="button" value="Add Munro" onClick="addRow('munroTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Munro" onClick="deleteRow('munroTable')"  /> 

            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="send" />
```

I have tried various different php commands to try and display the data entered, for example

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $value) {
// Do something with each valid friend entry ...
if ($value) {
    echo $value."<br />";
}
}
```

I have even attempted to display the size of the array to see if it stores the correct amount of data. This always returns 0.

```
echo "Number of munros =".sizeof($name);
```

I am unsure if the JavaScipt is interfering with this, although I doubt it. But just incase I have pasted it below.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 5){                           // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}else{
     alert("Maximum 5 Munros");

}
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Munros.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
}
```

This is my first time writing PHP outside of doing some small customisations to wordpress themes. I am using MAMP on mac.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: debug: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Your values form are passing correctly in array. To get $_POST['name'][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$_POST` to see a list of all parameters that were passed from the form

```
print_r($_POST)
```

Will print the full array of values